# How to change superset configuration config.py for production non-dev

Tags: docker-compose, apache-superset

I'm sorry for this trivial question... I have read the manual and have searched the internet for an answer.  I'm able to change the contents of the `superset/config.py` file using the "docker-compose up" that uses the `docker-compose.yml` file which is intended for development purposes.  The changes in the host `superset/config.py` file get deployed to the container of superset_app.

But when I try to launch superset using

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up
```

the changes to the host `superset/config.py` file don't get deployed.

What can I do?  Without this, then there is no way to setup important things like redis cache, permissions, and much more... is it impossible to tune the configuration of Superset when launched for production?

I know the docs say that if one wants to view changes to Superset's configuration one must use `docker-compose.yml`... but what is the best way to deploy Superset for production and still being able to modify the deployed `superset/config.py` file?

Answer (score 2):

The typical workflow when deploying with docker-compose is not to change `config.py`, leave that with its defaults.  Instead, create a new file called `superset_config.py` or `superset_config_docker.py` - either should work - in the directory `/docker/pythonpath_dev/` and override any values of `config.py` there that you want changed.  See this page, which is oddly separate from the rest of the docs: https://github.com/apache/superset/tree/master/docker#configuration

As to why your changes to `config.py` get picked up with the dev docker-compose file only, that's an interesting question.  My guess is the difference in the `x-superset-volumes` part of the two files.  Looks like the dev file is mounting directories as volumes that the non-dev one isn't?